# Query about inherited permissions

Tags: windows, permissions

Consider the following output from fileacl on a folder (Rob N) and a sub-folder (CAMRA) on our network:

```
[S:\Temp]fileacl "s:\temp\Rob N"
s:\temp\Rob N;BUILTIN\Administrators:F[I]
s:\temp\Rob N;CREATOR OWNER:U/F/F[I]
s:\temp\Rob N;COMPANY\Domain Users:F[I]
s:\temp\Rob N;NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:F[I]

[S:\Temp]fileacl "s:\temp\Rob N\CAMRA"
s:\temp\Rob N\CAMRA;BUILTIN\Administrators:F[I]
s:\temp\Rob N\CAMRA;COMPANY\rob.nicholson:F/U/U[I]
s:\temp\Rob N\CAMRA;CREATOR OWNER:U/F/F[I]
s:\temp\Rob N\CAMRA;COMPANY\Domain Users:F[I]
s:\temp\Rob N\CAMRA;NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:F[I]
```

The question is about that "company\rob.nicholson" entry in the "CAMRA" sub-folder. I'm intruiged where this ACE is coming from? If you try to remove it from the sub-folder, it says you cannot because it's inherited. But if it's inherited, how come the same trustee isn't shown on the root folder "Rob N"?

Is it something to do with CREATOR OWNER which I've never completely understood?

Thanks, Rob.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here is that you have the creator/owner ACL set, probably at the root of that drive.

The short version is:
If you have Creator Owner applied with inheritence at the top level (or above your current level at least) then when stuff is created by someone the stuff will pick up an 'inherited' special permissions for that person.

The longer version is :

http://networkadminkb.com/kb/Knowledge%20Base/ActiveDirectory/Creator%20Owner%20Explained.aspx

I came here today to ask the same question as you... now I know the answer, the question is; do I have the guts to remove 'creator owner' from the root of a clients file server.

(answer : not on a friday)